# How to clear jQuery validation error messages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin for client side validation.
Function `editUser()` is called on click of 'Edit User' button, which displays error messages.

But I want to clear error messages on my form, when I click on 'Clear' button, that calls a separate function `clearUser()`.

```
function clearUser() {
    // Need to clear previous errors here
}

function editUser(){
    var validator = $("#editUserForm").validate({
        rules: {
            userName: "required"
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        messages: {
            userName: errorMessages.E2
        }
    });

    if(validator.form()){
        // Form submission code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You want the `resetForm()` method:

```
var validator = $("#myform").validate(
   ...
   ...
);

$(".cancel").click(function() {
    validator.resetForm();
});
```

I grabbed it from the source of [one of their demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html).

Note: This code won't work for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: For those using bootstrap, there are cases where `resetForm()` does not clear all the instances of `.error` on the child elements of the form. This will leave residual CSS like red text color unless you call `.removeClass()`.

Example: `$('#myform .control-group').removeClass('error');`

Comment: Using bootstrap 3 this doesn't hide the field validation errors. What a shame.

Comment: It works for me with Bootstrap 3. Perhaps the problem is with your integration of both libraries?

Comment: No this resetForm will literally even rest the form data, too.

Comment: what @JLewkovich says using bootstrap3 is true, must implement a manual resetting jumping into the inspector and figuring out what classes are applying on errors

Comment: put this class on your (s)css:
.field-validation-valid{
    display: none;
}
and call the method .resetForm()

Answer (score 141):

I came across this issue myself. I had the need to conditionally validate parts of a form while the form was being constructed based on steps (i.e. certain inputs were dynamically appended during runtime). As a result, sometimes a select dropdown would need validation, and sometimes it would not. However, by the end of the ordeal, it needed to be validated. As a result, I needed a robust method which was not a workaround. I consulted the source code for `jquery.validate`.

Here is what I came up with:

Clear errors by indicating validation success

Call handler for error display

Clear all storage of success or errors

Reset entire form validation

Here is what it looks like in code:

```
function clearValidation(formElement){
 //Internal $.validator is exposed through $(form).validate()
 var validator = $(formElement).validate();
 //Iterate through named elements inside of the form, and mark them as error free
 $('[name]',formElement).each(function(){
   validator.successList.push(this);//mark as error free
   validator.showErrors();//remove error messages if present
 });
 validator.resetForm();//remove error class on name elements and clear history
 validator.reset();//remove all error and success data
}
//used
var myForm = document.getElementById("myFormId");
clearValidation(myForm);
```

minified as a jQuery extension:

```
$.fn.clearValidation = function(){var v = $(this).validate();$('[name]',this).each(function(){v.successList.push(this);v.showErrors();});v.resetForm();v.reset();};
//used:
$("#formId").clearValidation();
```

Comment: thats great , this solution is also working with "ValidationMessageFor"

Comment: Great! Works perfectly with Bootstrap and MVC!

Comment: First of all, thanks! Had this working great for years, but now I've discovered a performance issue: 

`showErrors` does some DOM manipulation and it is called for every element in the form. The browser froze for a couple of seconds when using this code on a form with ~ 30 controls.

The solution for me was to move `showErrors` out of the loop and just call it once right before `validator.resetForm`. 
As far as I can tell, it behaves exactly the same way and is a lot faster.

Comment: I've been using this until today that I found that if I use this method on the "Reset" button, it removes all the errors but there is no validation anymore... even if I try to validate again, everything is valid

Answer (score 62):

If you want to simply hide the errors:

```
$("#clearButton").click(function() {
  $("label.error").hide();
  $(".error").removeClass("error");
});
```

If you specified the `errorClass`, call that class to hide instead `error` (the default) I used above.

Comment: @mark - correct, but it's not designed to...they are still invalid, we're just hiding the error messages in this case.  This is alternative to the accepted answer for cases where you *specifically* want to hide (not ignore, e.g. disallow submission) the errors.  It comes up more often that you'd think :)

Comment: The problem is when you reset the form back and edit it again. My error dialog displays the count of errors and the count just keeps to sum up. Even 'resetForm' does not help.

Comment: Even I did this, but it leads to another issue. The validations don't apply the next time the dialog opens up!

Comment: This technique worked for me on a Bootstrap 3 website. Just had to alter the error class to the following:

`$(".has-error").removeClass("has-error");`

Answer (score 51):

If you didn't previously save the validators apart when attaching them to the form you can also just simply invoke

```
$("form").validate().resetForm();
```

as `.validate()` will return the same validators you attached previously (if you did so).

Comment: Worked, but if cross symbol available in the input field then you have also add 

$('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');

Answer (score 32):

If you want to do it without using a separate variable then

```
$("#myForm").data('validator').resetForm();
```

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately, `validator.resetForm()` does NOT work, in many cases.

I have a case where, if someone hits the "Submit" on a form with blank values, it should ignore the "Submit."  No errors.  That's easy enough.  If someone puts in a partial set of values, and hits "Submit," it should flag some of the fields with errors.  If, however, they wipe out those values and hit "Submit" again, it should clear the errors.  In this case, for some reason, there are no elements in the "currentElements" array within the validator, so executing `.resetForm()` does absolutely nothing.

There are bugs posted on this.

Until such time as they fix them, you need to use Nick Craver's answer, NOT Parrots' accepted answer.

Comment: Only in the JavaScript world is this an acceptable state of affairs.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
$("#myform").data('validator').resetForm();
```

Answer (score 6):

I think we just need to enter the inputs to clean everything

```
$("#your_div").click(function() {
  $(".error").html('');
  $(".error").removeClass("error");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want just clear validation labels you can use code from jquery.validate.js resetForm()

```
var validator = $('#Form').validate();

validator.submitted = {};
validator.prepareForm();
validator.hideErrors();
validator.elements().removeClass(validatorObject.settings.errorClass);
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested with:

```
$("div.error").remove();
$(".error").removeClass("error");
```

It will be ok, when you need to validate it again.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Bootstrap 3 code below will clean whole form: messages, icons and colors...

```
$('.form-group').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('has-success'); });
$('.form-group').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('has-error'); });
$('.form-group').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('has-feedback'); });
$('.help-block').each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
$('.form-control-feedback').each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Function using the approaches of **Travis J**, **JLewkovich** and **Nick Craver**...

```
// NOTE: Clears residual validation errors from the library "jquery.validate.js". 
// By Travis J and Questor
// [Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025232/3223785 ]
function clearJqValidErrors(formElement) {

    // NOTE: Internal "$.validator" is exposed through "$(form).validate()". By Travis J
    var validator = $(formElement).validate();

    // NOTE: Iterate through named elements inside of the form, and mark them as 
    // error free. By Travis J
    $(":input", formElement).each(function () {
    // NOTE: Get all form elements (input, textarea and select) using JQuery. By Questor
    // [Refs.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12862623/3223785 , 
    // https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ ]

        validator.successList.push(this); // mark as error free
        validator.showErrors(); // remove error messages if present
    });
    validator.resetForm(); // remove error class on name elements and clear history
    validator.reset(); // remove all error and success data

    // NOTE: For those using bootstrap, there are cases where resetForm() does not 
    // clear all the instances of ".error" on the child elements of the form. This 
    // will leave residual CSS like red text color unless you call ".removeClass()". 
    // By JLewkovich and Nick Craver
    // [Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086348/3223785 , 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086363/3223785 ]
    $(formElement).find("label.error").hide();
    $(formElement).find(".error").removeClass("error");
    $(formElement).find(".is-valid").removeClass("is-valid");

}

clearJqValidErrors($("#some_form_id"));
```

Comment: I had to add a new line of code at the end to properly work: 
$(formElement).find(".is-valid").removeClass("is-valid");

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide a validation in client side that is not part of a form submit you can use the following code:

```
$(this).closest("div").find(".field-validation-error").empty();
$(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried every single answer. The only thing that worked for me was:

```
$("#editUserForm").get(0).reset();
```

Using:

```
jquery-validate/1.16.0

jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other solutions worked for me.  `resetForm()` is clearly documented to reset the actual form, e.g. remove the data from the form, which is not what I want.  It just happens to sometimes not do that, but just remove the errors.  What finally worked for me is this:

```
validator.hideThese(validator.errors());
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using [aspnet jquery-validation-unobtrusive](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) and the following function cleared the validation errors for me:

```
function clearFormValidations(formElement) {
    $(formElement).validate().resetForm();

    // reset unobtrusive validation summary, if it exists
    $(formElement).find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
        .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
        .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
        .find("ul").empty();

    // reset unobtrusive field level, if it exists
    $(formElement).find("[data-valmsg-replace]")
        .removeClass("field-validation-error")
        .addClass("field-validation-valid")
        .empty();
}
```

usage:

```
// to clear the errors:
var myForm = document.getElementById('myFormId');
clearFormValidations(myForm);

// to validate again
var validator = $(myForm).validate();
validator.form();
```

I found the above function [here](https://vykantor.com/2014/04/25/reset-form-unobtrusive-jquery-validation/)

Comment: My code to remove the error message on the field StreetNumber: $("[data-valmsg-for='StreetNumber'] span").removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid").empty().css("padding", "0");

Answer (score 1):

I just did

`$('.input-validation-error').removeClass('input-validation-error');`

to remove red border on the input error fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
var validator = $("#myForm").validate();
validator.destroy();
```

This will destroy all the validation errors

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped with approach:

```
$(".field-validation-error span").hide();
```

Comment: None of other answers worked, but your answer worked well, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
onClick="$('.error').remove();"
```

on Clear button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for remove validation on the click on cancel

```
 function HideValidators() {
            var lblMsg = document.getElementById('<%= lblRFDChild.ClientID %>');
            lblMsg.innerHTML = "";           
            if (window.Page_Validators) {
                for (var vI = 0; vI < Page_Validators.length; vI++) {
                    var vValidator = Page_Validators[vI];
                    vValidator.isvalid = true;
                    ValidatorUpdateDisplay(vValidator);
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: This function is working on the cancel button and where else u want to use this one is good.try it

Answer (score 0):

To remove the validation summary you could write this

`$('div#errorMessage').remove();`

However, once you removed , again if validation failed it won't show this validation summary 
because you removed it. Instead use hide and display using the below code

```
$('div#errorMessage').css('display', 'none');

$('div#errorMessage').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I was disappointed at wasting my time on them. However there is an easy solution.

The solution was achieved by comparing the HTML mark up for the valid state and HTML mark up for the error state.

No errors would produce:

```
        <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"></div>
```

when an error occurs this div is populated with the errors and the class is changed to validation-summary-errors:

```
        <div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
```

The solution is very simple. Clear the HTML of the div which contains the errors and then change the class back to the valid state.

```
        $('.validation-summary-errors').html()            
        $('.validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
        $('.validation-summary-valid').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset `numberOfInvalids()` as well then add following line in `resetForm` function in `jquery.validate.js` file line number: 415.

```
this.invalid = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(FORM_ID).validate().resetForm();` is still not working as expected.

I am clearing form with `resetForm()`. It works in all case except one!!

When I load any form via Ajax and apply form validation after loading my dynamic `HTML`, then after when I try to reset the form with `resetForm()` and it fails and also it flushed off all validation I am applying on form elements.

So kindly do not use this for Ajax loaded forms OR manually initialized validation.

**P.S.** You need to use **Nick Craver's** answer for such scenario as I explained.

Answer (score 0):

`validator.resetForm()` method clear error text. But **if you want to remove the RED border** from fields you have to remove the class `has-error`

```
$('#[FORM_ID] .form-group').removeClass('has-error');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write own code because everyone uses a different class name. I am resetting jQuery validation by this code.

```
$('.error').remove();
        $('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');
```

Answer (score 0):

None of above worked for bootstrap 4.
This solved problem for me:

```
$('#formId .invalid-feedback').remove()
$('#formId input').removeClass('is-valid');
$('#formId input').removeClass('is-invalid');
```

Answer (score 0):

For v1.19.0 for JQuery Validation I found this one line of code worked for me:

```
$('.field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-error').addClass('field-validation-valid').html('');
```

In effect making the field appear valid to the user but when they click submit again the validation re-fires.

Answer (score 0):

I took what other have posted and dug a little deeper and came up with this:
In my form I added

```
class="EditProv"
```

to all my elements.

```
var validator = $("#FormEditProvider").validate();
validator.resetForm();
validator.reset();
$('#FormEditProvider .EditProv').removeClass('input-validation-error');
$("[id^=Provider_][id$=error]").html("");
```

The first line fires the validator which you will need for the rest of it.
The second and third lines are the "official" way.
The fourth line finds everything with the class "EditProv" and remove the "input-validation-error" from classes.
Finally, the fifth line clears the error message text. For my form, the jquery validation plug in was adding or modifying this span:

```
<span id="Provider_MedicareNum-error" class="">
```

Where "Provider_MedicareNum" is the id of the element and jquery adds the -error to it.