# What does jQuery.fn mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the `fn` here mean?

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

Answer (score 886, accepted):

In jQuery, the `fn` property is just an alias to the `prototype` property.

The `jQuery` identifier (or `$`) is just a *constructor function*, and all instances created with it, inherit from the constructor's prototype.

A simple constructor function:

```
function Test() {
  this.a = 'a';
}
Test.prototype.b = 'b';

var test = new Test(); 
test.a; // "a", own property
test.b; // "b", inherited property
```

A simple structure that resembles the architecture of jQuery:

```
(function() {
  var foo = function(arg) { // core constructor
    // ensure to use the `new` operator
    if (!(this instanceof foo))
      return new foo(arg);
    // store an argument for this example
    this.myArg = arg;
    //..
  };

  // create `fn` alias to `prototype` property
  foo.fn = foo.prototype = {
    init: function () {/*...*/}
    //...
  };

  // expose the library
  window.foo = foo;
})();

// Extension:

foo.fn.myPlugin = function () {
  alert(this.myArg);
  return this; // return `this` for chainability
};

foo("bar").myPlugin(); // alerts "bar"
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be true?  Can I assume a call to jQuery.prototype is exactly the same as jQuery.fn?  My worry is if jQuery does some magic when you call .fn then they aren't interchangeable

Comment: how can you extend 'foo' in your example if 'foo' was declared only inside of the anonymous function?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I am missing something..  'window.foo = foo' gives 'foo' a global scope? never new that, I'll add that to my list of techniques to learn.

Comment: @E.E.33 If I'm not mistaken, the global scope in javascript simply means that your variable is a parameter of the window object.

Comment: @Shawn you are correct, that is why 'foo' had to explicitly be assigned to 'window.foo'. otherwise, the window object wouldn't have the reference.

Comment: Can you explain why you need `return this;`?

Comment: @Imray - `return this` to allow [chaining](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining), so you could do `foo("bar").myPlugin().otherPlugin()`

Comment: @Shawn I think it would be called a property, not a parameter, right? A parameter would be the 'a' variable here `function func1 (a) { ... }`, and a property would be the 'a' variable here `var foo = {}; foo.a = 'a'`.

Comment: Because of the prototype tree search, the new method will work on an existing object too: `var Foo = function(){};var bar = new Foo();Foo.prototype.x=function(){alert("x");};bar.x();` alerts "x".

Answer (score 164):

`fn` literally refers to the jquery `prototype`.

This line of code is in the source code:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
 //list of functions available to the jQuery api
}
```

But the real tool behind `fn` is its availability to hook your own functionality into jQuery. Remember that jquery will be the parent scope to your function, so `this` will refer to the jquery object.

```
$.fn.myExtension = function(){
 var currentjQueryObject = this;
 //work with currentObject
 return this;//you can include this if you would like to support chaining
};
```

So here is a simple example of that. Lets say I want to make two extensions, one which puts a blue border, and which colors the text blue, and I want them chained.

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/CVrFU/)***

```
$.fn.blueBorder = function(){
 this.each(function(){
  $(this).css("border","solid blue 2px");
 });
 return this;
};
$.fn.blueText = function(){
 this.each(function(){
  $(this).css("color","blue");
 });
 return this;
};
```

Now you can use those against a class like this:

```
$('.blue').blueBorder().blueText();
```

(I know this is best done with css such as applying different class names, but please keep in mind this is just a demo to show the concept)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025232/1026459) has a good example of a full fledged extension.

Comment: Can't you just skip the `each` in your example code? `$.fn.blueBorder = function(){ this.css("border","solid blue 2px"); return this; };` would work fine, as `.css()` alerady iterates over the elements.

Comment: @SoonDead - You certainly could because if the jQuery object holds a collection then the `css` function will automatically iterate over them internally with each. It was just an example of showing the differences in `this` where the outer one is the jquery object and the inner one references the element itself.

Comment: @SoonDead Good comment, but I really like how Travis J explained the idea/principle. :)

Comment: This is the best comment -- Knowing that fn is just an alias is not nearly as useful as knowing why anyone should care, and this answer demonstrated it beautifully.

Comment: Well, why not just use `$.prototype.blueBorder` ? Is this just so that you don't have to type more letters?

Comment: After going through the other answers, I found this one to be easier to understand the main concept. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 152):

`jQuery.fn` is defined shorthand for `jQuery.prototype`.  From the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L76):

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    // ...
}
```

That means `jQuery.fn.jquery` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype.jquery`, which returns the current jQuery version.  Again from the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L192):

```
// The current version of jQuery being used
jquery: "@VERSION",
```

Comment: I like this answer. I shows exactly how to find the definition inside the source code, and then how to interpret the definition in a useful manner.  The good ol' "teach a man to fish" method of answering. +1.

Comment: but what is the purpose of doing that? just saving couple of keystroke?

Comment: @slier: yes, pretty much.

Comment: i bet there is other purpose..attaching function to $.fn, will make static function

Answer (score 19):

The **$.fn** is an alias for **jQuery.prototype** which allows you to extend jQuery with your own functions.

> For Example:

```
 $.fn.something = function{}
```

> will allow you to use

```
$("#element").something()
```

The **$.fn** is also synonymous with **jQuery.fn.**

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Its possible to return a value? how?

Answer (score 3):

In the jQuery source code we have `jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {...}` since `jQuery.prototype` is an object the value of `jQuery.fn` will simply be a reference to the same object that `jQuery.prototype` already references.

To confirm this you can check `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype` if that evaluates `true` (which it does) then they reference the same object