# Wrap existing jquery event with defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to figure out how I can wrap the click event. Eg this is the code I want.

```
$("#test").aclick(function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

The only thing that aclick does is use the e.preventDefault automatically.
Is it something like?

```
$.fn.aclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return $.fn.click.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **binding** a handler, the event object `e` doesn't exist yet. You need to create a default event handler that calls the supplied one:

```
$.fn.aclick = function (handler) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var el = this;
        $(el).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            handler.call(el, e);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I think i just went over into the deep end... to understand this code is going to take me a month. Care to offer an explanation, my javascript / jQuery is rusty...

Comment: Here's a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean