# What is going on with the javascript and the fn?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

I have some script on a page trying to work out what its doing:

```
(function ($, window, undefined)
{

    var 
    // String constants for data names
    dataFlag = "watermark",
    dataClass = "watermarkClass",
    dataFocus = "watermarkFocus",
    dataFormSubmit = "watermarkSubmit",
    dataMaxLen = "watermarkMaxLength",
    dataPassword = "watermarkPassword",
    dataText = "watermarkText",

    // Copy of native jQuery regex use to strip return characters from element value
    rreturn = /\r/g,

    // Includes only elements with watermark defined
    selWatermarkDefined = "input:data(" + dataFlag + "),textarea:data(" + dataFlag + ")",

    // Includes only elements capable of having watermark
    selWatermarkAble = "input:text,input:password,input[type=search],input:not([type]),textarea",

    // triggerFns:
    // Array of function names to look for in the global namespace.
    // Any such functions found will be hijacked to trigger a call to
    // hideAll() any time they are called.  The default value is the
    // ASP.NET function that validates the controls on the page
    // prior to a postback.
    // 
    // Am I missing other important trigger function(s) to look for?
    // Please leave me feedback:
    // http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/issues/list
    triggerFns = [
        "Page_ClientValidate"
    ],

    // Holds a value of true if a watermark was displayed since the last
    // hideAll() was executed. Avoids repeatedly calling hideAll().
    pageDirty = false,

    // Detects if the browser can handle native placeholders
    hasNativePlaceholder = ("placeholder" in document.createElement("input"));


    /*******************************************************/
    /* Enable / disable other control on trigger condition */
    /*******************************************************/
    $.fn.TriggerContol = function (options)
    {
```

Im struggling with the last two lines. Why has the developer used fn, what does this mean?

I understand that this whole file is basically a self invoking anonymous function designed to attach functions to the Jquery library so you can do jQuery(x).TriggerControl. Im just wondering what this particular construct means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, `jQuery.fn` is simply a reference to `jQuery.prototype`.

So to understand what is happening, you really need to understand *prototypal inheritance*.

All objects created from the `jQuery` constructor will inherit any property that exists on the `jQuery.prototype` object.

Take this simplified example:

```
function jQuery() {
      // empty constructor function
}

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype;  // Make a "fn" property that simply references the 
                               //    jQuery.prototype object.

// So assigning a property to jQuery.fn 
//    is the same as assigning it to jQuery.prototype
jQuery.fn.sayHello = function() { alert( "Hi!" ); };

// Create an object from the jQuery constructor
var obj = new jQuery;

// Our new object will automatically inherit the "sayHello" function
obj.sayHello();  // "Hi!"
```

This is obviously very simple, and jQuery does much more than just this, but it is the *prototypal inheritance* that allows all jQuery objects to have the same set of methods.

To add a new method to all jQuery objects, you just add to its prototype.

```
jQuery.fn.sayGoodbye = function() { alert("Goodbye!"); };

// call the new method on our original object
obj.sayGoodbye();  // Goodbye!
```

As you can see, the `sayGoodbye` properly magically appeared, even though we didn't directly add that property to our `obj`.

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W9r9D/)** of the above code.

---

I would assume that the reason they offer `jQuery.fn` as a property is simply because it is shorter, and perhaps easier to understand for someone who doesn't know how prototypal inheritance works.

Answer (score 1):

With the fn operator you can create your own methods for a (set of) elements. In this case that method is called TriggerControl and can be called like:

```
$('.someclass').TriggerControl(someoptions);
```

Take look at [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) page for more info.