# What's the purpose of jQuery.fn

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

Part of the jQuery source code states:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
```

Given this, wouldn't

```
$.fn.adamPlugin = function(options) {  
   return this.each(function() {   });  
};
```

Be identical to

```
$.prototype.adamPlugin = function(options) {  
   return this.each(function() {   });  
};
```

If so, what's the point of `$.fn`?  Adding things to a prototype is fairly common in JavaScript, so I can't quite understand why the jQuery folks would try to abstract this away.

Comment: I'd imagine the short-hand allows them to make the library smaller... also, I hear they're big proponents of _writing less_.

Comment: Why $ for jQuery? Replacing the one with the other is identical, too.

Comment: Paul Irish explains it a little [here](http://paulirish.com/2011/11-more-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) as well.

Comment: @antisanity: That's probably it. In addition, a minifier could not rename the `prototype` property as it is a special name, but it could rename `fn`.

Comment: @antisanity - that's it.  It makes the library size smaller, and is friendlier to minifiers.  Can you put that as an answer before this question gets closed?

Comment: Look at the source code line 97 of 1.7.1

Comment: *"can't quite understand why the jQuery folks would try to abstract this away"* jQuery seems to want to abstract nearly *everything* away. This is unfortunate.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. The other question asks *what* it is, which Adam knows already. The question is here is *why* it is used and what's the advantage. Though I think that this question is better asked directly to the developer team.

Comment: @Felix - you're right.  I think antisanity nailed the answer.  If this gets re-opened I think that's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a convenient alias for `prototype` that's all.