# Can someone help explain jQuery extend in a very simple way?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following code:

```
     $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "datetime-uk-pre": function (a) {
            from = a.split(' ');
            var ukDatea = from[0].split('/');
            var ukTimea = from[1].split(':');
            return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0] + ukTimea[1] + ukTimea[0]) * 1;
        },
        "datetime-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },
        "datetime-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });

    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
            var ukDatea = a.split('/');

            return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
        },
        "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },
        "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });
```

I read about about extend but still don't understand what it is doing. Can someone help explain this. What I am looking for is a simple explanation as possible.  Also can I combine these two code blocks in some way.

This is code to give datatables a different way to sort. But what does it mean:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort
```

Comment: Yes, it merges the contents of two or more objects together into the *first* object. Have a look on [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) specs.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean for $.fn

Comment: In your example `$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort` options are rewritten(or just added) from the second argument(object) of `extend()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataTables` provides several [sorting](http://legacy.datatables.net/development/sorting) options in the base package. The one you are looking at is called [**Type based column sorting**](http://legacy.datatables.net/development/sorting#type_based), which basically will try to sort your column based on its type. DataTables already provisions default sorting functions for the most common types, such as `Date`, `Numeric`, and `HTML`. These are registered as properties in an object called `oSort`, which is accessible using `$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort`. This object looks like this:

```
oSort = {
  "string-pre": function ( a ) {
    // ...
  },
  "numeric": function ( a ) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, if you need a custom sorting function for a custom type, you can extend the `oSort` object, by adding additional *keys*, or properties, to the `oSort` object.

For example, to add a new type, called `date-uk-pre`, you could use:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['date-uk-pre'] = function ( a ) {
  // ...
}
```

That is, you are *extending* the `oSort` with a new property called `date-uk-pre`. jQuery's **[`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)** is nothing but a shortcut for this. Instead of adding manually each property, for each new type, you pass a new object, with all your new types (e.g., `date-uk-pre`, `datetime-uk-pre`, and jQuery **merges** them with the existing `oSort` object, effectively extending it with the new functions. You can even combine both `$.extend()`s to a single one:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-uk-pre": function (a) {
        var ukDatea = a.split('/');

        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },
    "date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    },
    "datetime-uk-pre": function (a) {
        from = a.split(' ');
        var ukDatea = from[0].split('/');
        var ukTimea = from[1].split(':');
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0] + ukTimea[1] + ukTimea[0]) * 1;
    },
    "datetime-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "datetime-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
var m1 = {'a':'a','b':'b'};
var m2 = {'c':'c','d':'d'};
var m3 = {'e':'e','f':'f'};

$.extend(m1,m2,m3);

console.log("m1:");
console.log(m1);

//Result : 
//m1:
//{'a':'a','b':'b','c':'c','d':'d','e':'e','f':'f'};
```

Also, for one argumnt:

```
$.extend(m1)
```

is equivalent to

```
$.extend($, m1);
```

or

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery, m1);
```

So jQuery would be extended. Then jQuery will contain two additional properties in my particular example above: 'a':'a' and 'b','b' . So $.a would return 'a'.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ for more information.

Comment: So can I combine the above one after the other?

Comment: Yes, let's say you already did $.extend(m1,m2,m3); in my example. If you then issued something like this line: $.extend(m1, {'h':'h'}); yes, you are right, it would combine again! it would indeed add the h key and h property and yes there would be a,b,c,d,e,f,g and now h as keys and values in m1, and yes you could continue to do this again and again if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The extend function adds properties defined in the second argument to the object in the first argument. Commonly it is used to add more functionality to a plugin as it is in the code above. The code above adds six functions to the `$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort` object. Which from Google search is [this plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting). After extending the plugin, you can do something like:

```
$('selector').dataTableExt.oSort.date-uk-pre();
```