# Simple explanation for why datatables uses $.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData

Tags: jquery

I saw a post out there:

[what does $.fn mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

However I still don't understand it. Can someone explain this in very simple terms to me. Why did they choose to specify it this way?

Comment: which part did you not understand exactly ? The prototype part, the constructor part or something else ?

Comment: To understand prototypes a little better have a read of this -> http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/ its long but well worth a read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.fn` is just an alias for `jQuery.prototype`. To write a jQuery [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), such as DataTables, one usually starts by adding a new function property to `$.fn`.

In simpler terms, when you write `$.fn.pluginName`, you are ***extending*** jQuery's [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), by adding a new function called `pluginName` to it. This way, you can call it using, for example, `$("#myElement").pluginName()`. That's basically what DataTables does, it provides an extension to jQuery called `dataTablesExt`.

Now, this plugin has several properties. One of them, is called `afnSortData` (which you could also refer to using `jQuery.prototype.dataTableExt.afnSortData`). This way, the plugin properties are ***scoped*** to the `dataTableExt` object/plugin. DataTables could have opted to define it in the global namespace, but this way, someone could overwrite `afnSortData` with, say, `{}` and break the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, the `fn` property is just an alias to the prototype property.

The `jQuery` identifier (or `$`) is just a *constructor function*, and all instances created with it, inherit from the constructor's prototype.

---

Source: [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

So it stand just for `jQuery.prototype`.

```
$.fn === jQuery.prototype
```

**What .prototype is?**

In JavaScript, the prototype is the mechanism which provides inheritance.

Example: `String.prototype` refers to the prototype object of Strings, which contains (among other things) methods which can be invoked on any String.

Comment: I read the post and also linked to it in my question. However what you said I can't understand. I don't know what the prototype property is so knowing it's an alias still doesn't tell me anything.  Thanks

Comment: I added the explanation of it as well. Just inheritance.