# Difference between $.fn.fancybox and $.fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

Please tell me the difference between the two above. How they are different from each other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean

Comment: Removed my answer since this is a duplicate.

Comment: I read this before... why you removed your answer. and when the fancybox is called from outside which one is called

Comment: @user1575229, try reading the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.  It explains it very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

$.fn is the prototype used to jQuery objects created from $("..."). SO by calling .fn you are extending the defaults.

$ is the jQuery factory and namespace.

For Fancybox 2.0, the ".fn" is dropped.

Comment: in fancybox there are two methods $.fn.fancybox and $.fancybox. I can guess about the first one but what does the second one say now? please elaborate this don't get it.