# What is the difference between $.addMessage = function () { and $.fn.addMessage = function () {

Tags: javascript, typescript

I realize that one is a prototype can someone tell me the difference between these two?

```
$.addMessage = function () {
```

and

```
$.fn.addMessage = function () {
```

From what I can see one extends JQuery and the other JQueryStatic in typescript

```
interface JQuery {
    addMessage();
}

interface JQueryStatic {
  addMessage();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does jQuery.fn mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

Comment: @Jan - Thanks for the link? Can you show me where in the link you nominated as a duplicate does it explain the difference between the two ways to declare a function.

Comment: I said 'possible'. The other answer is sufficient if you understand the Javascript object model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a function as

```
$.addMessage = function(){
```

you can later access the function as

```
$.addMessage()
```

Semantically, the function has no relation to specific jQuery instances, and may be regarded to as an **equivalent of a static method** (belongs to a class) in Java.

---

If you add a function as

```
$.fn.addMessage = function(){
```

Since jQuery defines $.fn as an alias to $.prototype, this is equivalent to

```
$.prototype.addMessage = function(){
```

Javascript automatically assigns `Class.prototype` as a prototype of the objects created with `new Class()`. `$(...)` uses `new $(...)` internally, meaning it does create new objects with `$` as the constructor. This means that `$.fn.addMessage` can also be accessed as

```
$(".messageContainer").addMessage()
```

Semantically, `$.fn.addMessage` is related to specific jQuery instances. It means that `this` inside the `addMessage` function does not refer to `$.fn`, but rather to `$(...)`. `$.fn` may thus be regarded to as **an equivalent of an instance method** (belongs to an instance) in Java.

---

In other words, if you declare your function as

```
$.addMessage = function(){
```

, you use it as

```
$.addMessage()
```

If you declare it your function as

```
$.fn.addMessage = function(){
```

, you use it as

```
$(".messageContainer").addMessage()
```