# Colorbox doesn't work after update from v1.3.19 to v1.4.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I updated Colorbox.min.js file from v1.3.19 to v1.4.6 and some of my colorboxes doesn't work. I don't get any error on page and Chrome's console.

I checked for [changelog](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/tree/1.x#changelog) but I didn't find the anser. Can you help please?

(I use jQuery 1.7.2)

- This doesn't work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="emailDialog()">e-mail</a>
```

```
function emailDialog(){  
    $.fn.colorbox({  
        width:"700px", height:"550px",  
        iframe:true, href:"/contact",  
        opacity:0.6  
    });  
}
```

- This works well:

```
<a href="http://example.com/1.jpeg" class="colorbox-avatar" title="some title" rel="nofollow" >photo</a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".colorbox-avatar").colorbox({  
        rel:'colorbox-avatar',  
        scrolling: false,  
        current: "",  
        slideshow:true, slideshowAuto:false,  
        opacity:0.6,  
        width:"60%" , height:"60%"  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call it without the `.fn` ... so `$.colorbox({...})`

(`$.fn` is used for [developing jQuery plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and is really just [shorthand for `$.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)).

```
function emailDialog(){
    $.colorbox({
        width:"700px", height:"550px",
        iframe:true, href:"/contact",
        opacity:0.6
    });   
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/4tkf5/)