# Add function to prototype of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm extending the [jquery.contentcarousel plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/), and I've reached a specific point where I'm defining new functions via `__prototype__`. I shrunk the code down to demonstrate the essential part:

```
(function($) {
    var   aux      = {
    navigate : function(){
        //...
      },
    }
    methods = {
        init     : function( options ) {

            return this.each(function() {

                var $el        = $(this);

                //THIS IS THE SLIPPERY LINE:
                $el.__proto__.scrollOneLeft = function() {
                    aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, $.extend(settings, {sliderSpeed: 10, sliderEasing: ''}), cache );
                };
            });

        }
    }

    $.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
        }
    }; 

})(jQuery);
```

This works on the modern browsers, but the problem is that `$el.__proto__` is not working in IE9 and IE10 (yet). I'm not a jQuery Ninja, so I guess that this isn't the proper solution anyway.

So my question is, how would you define a new method properly in this scenario?

Comment: Be careful, you overwrite the function in a loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is not the *proper* way of doing this. jQuery has great extensibility capability, and this case is already covered in a cross-browser way.

You can define new functions on the jQuery array object, by:

```
jQuery.fn.asdfize = function () {
    this.html('asdf');
    return this; // for chainability
}
```

You can than use `$('div').asdfize();` to replace all div's innerHTML with `asdf`.

This is basically what you need, as `$(this)` has the jQuery array object (`jQuery.fn`) as it's prototype.

The old jQuery wiki has a nice article about [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) which covers this.

**EDIT**:

You have already done this in your code with `$.fn.contentcarousel`. How is this other case different?

**EDIT2**:

In this part of your code:

```
return this.each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.__proto__.scrollOneLeft = function() { ... };
});
```

You overwrite the `scrollOneLeft` function in every iteration of each. It's probably not what you want!

You might want to define the function only once instead, but use `this` inside it as it will be the jQuery object you call it on.

Comment: Hey SoonDead, thanks for the solution! It is working so far. I wouldn't say I understand it yet, so now I'm going to read about `$.fn`

Comment: Basically it's the [prototype of `$(this)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean) :)

Comment: Ok, so `$el` should be replaced with `this`? As I read in the plugins authoring guide it's wrapped unnecessarily (as `$this`) anyways, right?

Comment: `this` is the [object the function is called on](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/). So `$(this)` would be unnecessary in the `scrollOneLeft` function yes, as it is already the jQuery object. But keep in mind that a lot of jQuery functions (like `.each()`) call their callback functions on the *raw DOM element*. Don't mix up these 2 cases. :)