# Always close current div regardless of which trigger you click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

How is it possible to close a div that's currently open when you click on its trigger that usely opens the div or any other trigger (that opens a different event on the page)?

So basicaly I have two links: Login and Register. When you click Register, the Login block/div disappears and the Register div shows up. When I hit Login, the Register div hides and the Login div shows up.

Also when I, e.g. click Login and the Login div is already shown - the Login div must hide aswell.

How do I accomplish this? I tried for days now, but unfortunately i'm a beginner to jQuery and my skills in jQuery aren't great at the moment. I made the following script that works. I only can hide/show divs when you click the same trigger. If you click Register AND Login the divs will just show up on top of eachother, without the hiding.

```
;(function($) {
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq.fn.login_switch = function(options) {
    var o = $jq.extend({}, $jq.fn.login_switch.defaults, options);
    var $this = $jq(this);

  $jq(this).click(function(e) 
  {  
      e.preventDefault(); 
    // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
    $jq(this).closest("div#wrapper").children("div#member_login").eq(0)[o.method](o.speed);

  });

};
$jq.fn.reg_switch = function(options) {
    var o = $jq.extend({}, $jq.fn.reg_switch.defaults, options);
    var $this = $jq(this);

  $jq(this).click(function(e) 
  {  
      e.preventDefault(); 
    // hides matched elements if shown, shows if hidden 
    $jq(this).closest("div#wrapper").children("div#member_reg").eq(0)[o.method](o.speed);
  });

};
$jq.fn.login_switch.defaults = {
    speed : "slow",
    method: "slideFadeToggle"
};
$jq("a.log-expand").login_switch();

$jq.fn.reg_switch.defaults = {
    speed : "slow",
    method: "slideFadeToggle"
};
$jq("a.reg-expand").reg_switch();


var msie = false;
if(typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') { msie = true; }

$jq.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, function() { 
    if (msie) { this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); }
    if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) { callback(); }
  }); 
};

};
})(jQuery);
```

My html is:

```
    <div id="member_reg" style="display:none;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
            REGISTRATION.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="member_login" style="display:none;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
                LOGIN.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

with the trigger buttons:

```
<ul class="user">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="reg-expand register">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="log-expand login">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please share your `HTML` for the `divs` and buttons?

Comment: Have you checked out the toggle() method in jquery? you can easily achieve showing/hiding element using that.

Comment: What you have here is overkill

Comment: zgood, like I said, i'm no expert in jQuery. I'm just starting with it. How can I do it differently with less overkill then?

Comment: I can make a fiddle for you. Sorry wasn't trying to be a dick, but I know it came across as that.

Comment: I've added my HTML to my first post. And yes I've checked toggle() function of jquery. But have no clue, how to get it done with it.

Comment: zgood, no probs. A fiddle would be awesome. Allows me to study it a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G4YHP/) for you with the behavior I think you are trying to achieve.

Let me know if you have any questions or if I'm way off base.

HTML

```
<button id="btnLogin" data-bound="login">Login</button><button id="btnRegister" data-bound="register">Register</button>

<hr />

<div id="login" class="area" data-state="closed">
    Login div
</div>

<div id="register" class="area" data-state="closed">
    Register div
</div>
```

CSS

```
.area{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:0;
    margin:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
}
#login{
    background:#41cc36;
}
#register{
    background:#3764e3;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').bind('click', function(){
        //close any open areas
        $('.area').each(function(){
            if($(this).data('state') == 'open'){
                $(this).animate({'height': 0}, 750, function(){
                    $(this).data('state', 'closed');
                });
            }
        });
        //retrieve the div we need to toggle and it's state
        var divID = $(this).data('bound'),
            div = $('#' + divID),
            state = div.data('state');
        //animate the div based on it's state, then set the new state
        if(state == 'closed'){
            div.animate({'height': 100}, 750, function(){
                div.data('state', 'open');
            });            
        }else{
            div.animate({'height': 0}, 750, function(){
                div.data('state', 'closed');
            });
        }
    });

    //init
    $('#btnLogin').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is exactly what I tried to achieve. First thing I noticed is that your approach is much different than mine. Why's that if I may ask? Why not try to make it with jQuery's toggle()? Also I never have tried data-bound and data-state before in HTML. Is it HTML5?

Btw, all the containers are now closed after a page load. How to show i.e. #login as a default container being open already?

Comment: Well there really is no right or wrong way, just a ton of different ways to code the same thing lol. In your approach you are creating a like a plugin for jQuery using `fn` which is like `prototype`... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean). Whereas I am just directly attaching click events to your buttons on page load. Your approach is longer, but makes the code re-useable on different pages. You could even combine both and make jQuery plugin using my code approach. The best approach usually depends on the project and what you're comfortable with.

Comment: You could use `toggle()` if you wanted to fade the div in and out, but I am animating heights (just because I like how it looks) so `toggle()` would not work for me.

Comment: `data` is a [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/) thing and an [HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) thing working together. Basically you can create any custom attribute in HTML (like data-myproperty or data-foo) and then access that value via jQuery like this: `$('#someDiv').data('foo');` or set the value: `$('#someDiv').data('foo', 'new value');`. You could also use global javascript variables to store values if you want, I just think this `data` approach is cleaner.

Comment: I have updated this answer to include an initial `btnLogin` click so that your Login div will be open when the page first loads.

Comment: Once again, thank you for your time and great explanations. I will play a bit more with it and start reading about it. :) Cheers