# Trouble with Flot for Wordpress Tooltip plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tooltip, flot

I'm trying to enable tooltips for Flot for Wordpress and am having problems with it when I add in a certain function and I need this to work from what I've tried to decipher onnline.

I downloaded the latest version of tooltips for flot charts and loaded the script when the plugin is loaded.

The chart I have create loads perfect when the following js code is not in the code or when the function is empty like below too.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code that is stopping my chart appearing?

Cheers in advance, Alan.

This is code I believe I need to make the tooltips work

```
 function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $("<div id="tooltip">" + contents + "</div>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            top: y + 5,
            left: x + 20,
            border: "2px solid #4572A7",
            padding: "2px",     
            size: "10",   
            "background-color": "#fff",
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }
```

This is what works when I remove the inside of the code

```
function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        position: "absolute"
}
```

Here full code below:

```
echo ' <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( $path ) . '/flot-for-wp/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( $path ) . '/flot-for-wp/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( $path ) . '/flot-for-wp/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<link href="' . plugins_url( $path ) . '/flot-for-wp/flot/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="placeholder" style="width:95%; height:85%; max-width:100%; margin:auto;"></div>
';
echo '
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" id="source">


var lie_results = [ ';
foreach($chartdata as $row){
echo '[' .$row['mentalerrors_date'] . ',' .$row['mentalerrors_lie'] . '],';
}
echo ' ];

var options_results = [ ';
foreach($chartdata as $row){
echo '[' .$row['mentalerrors_date'] . ',' .$row['mentalerrors_options'] . '],';
}
echo ' ];

var context_results = [ ';
foreach($chartdata as $row){
echo '[' .$row['mentalerrors_date'] . ',' .$row['mentalerrors_context'] . '],';
}
echo ' ];

var decide_results = [ ';
foreach($chartdata as $row){
echo '[' .$row['mentalerrors_date'] . ',' .$row['mentalerrors_decide'] . '],';
}
echo ' ];


var dataset = [
    {
        label: "Lie",
        data: lie_results
    },  {
        label: "Context",
        data: context_results
    }, {
        label: "Options",
        data: options_results
    },{
        label: "Decide",
        data: decide_results
    }
];


var options = {
    xaxis: { mode: "time", tickSize: [2, "month"] },
    yaxes: [{ min: ' .$min_count . ', max: ' .$max_count . ' },{},{},{}],
    points: { show: true, symbol: "circle", fill: true },
    lines: { show: true, },
    legend: { noColumns: 0, labelFormatter: function (label, series) { return "<font color=\"white\">" + label + "</font>";}, backgroundColor: "#000", backgroundOpacity: 0.9, labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000", position: "nw"},
    grid: { hoverable: true, mouseActiveRadius: 8 }
};


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
var plot = $.plot(placeholder,dataset,options);
$("#placeholder").UseTooltip();
}
);


var previousPoint = null;

$.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
    $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {                         
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();

                var x = item.datapoint[0];
                var y = item.datapoint[1];                

                console.log(x+","+y)

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                  x + "<br>" + "<strong>" + y + "</strong> (" + item.series.label + ")");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
};

function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $("<div id=\'tooltip\'>" + contents + "</div>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            top: y + 5,
            left: x + 20,
            border: "2px solid #4572A7",
            padding: "2px",     
            size: "8",   
            opacity: 0.85,
            background: "#4572A7",
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    };




</script></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using javascript, get in the habit of checking the debugger console for errors.  This is invalid javascript:

```
$("<div id="tooltip">" + contents + "</div>")
```

It produces:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Why?  Because it's not properly quoted.

Try:

```
"<div id=\"tooltip\">" + contents + "</div>"
```

The quotes around tooltip are escaped.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for that. I'm still learning Javascript. The chart now loads with the code so it must have been the \ that was missing. Now to trouble shoot the code to make the tooltips work!! Any recommendations for a good site to learn JS?

Comment: Just found the chrome debugger and it's giving me 2 more errors

[link]http://i59.tinypic.com/o86tz8.png[/link]

Comment: @Alan, the first error is caused by the second.  The second error means that `$.fn` is not defined yet (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean).  Make sure you are loading jquery before that code executes.

Comment: I've checked the source code for my page and it's loaded at the top as

Comment: I've checked the source code for my page and it's loaded at the top as
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
This is the error I get using the above script [link]http://i62.tinypic.com/nloo5d.png
And this is what I get when I use the following script - [link]http://i59.tinypic.com/242va4x.png
Thanks again for all the help so far

Comment: @Alan, can you show all your `<script src=`?  Edit your question above, it's too hard to read in the comment.  My guess is that you are loading it out of order.

Comment: Updated it there @Mark not sure if I have included everything you need but this is the file that I run to generate my graph. There is still a few errors coming up on the javascript console but the tooltips are appearing now.