# jQuery plugin static method $.fn.plugin.method vs $.plugin.method

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

The [official jQuery resource](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/) seems to indicate that you create a static method for your plugin using `$.fn.plugin.staticMethod` but that means that your public API requires calling `$.fn.plugin.staticMethod()`, which I find cumbersome.

Is there anything wrong with defining `$.fn.plugin` for your plugin and `$.plugin.staticMethod` for your static method, and what's the difference?

Further, what's the difference between:

```
$.extend({
  plugin : {
    staticMethod : function(){ }
  }
});
```

and

```
$.plugin = {
  staticMethod : function(){ }
};
```

Comment: Duplicate? `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean

Comment: The link you provided was helpful, but I don't think it answers the entire question, which also deals with creating a static method.