# JQuery Plugin File Loading But Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tablesorter

I am attempting to load the tablesorter JQuery plugin, I am using JQuery version 2.1.1 and the latest version of tablesorter. I load them in the following order :

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried forks of tablesorter and none of them work. I tested that I had the right plugin file location by putting

```
alert("Plugin File");
```

at the top of the file and this works when the page loads.

None of the plugins functionality is working and I tested it using this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  if(jQuery.fn.tablesorter){
    alert("pluginloaded");
   }
     jQuery.tablesorter();
   }
}
```

The alert does not work and firebug reports that tablesorter is not a function.

Comment: Check the path of the files, it sounds like the file isn't being found. Verify this by looking at the network tab in Firebug to check that the file is loading.

Comment: the file definitely is being found, as I said I put an Alert in it which triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is a combination of problems.

1. The document ready function doesn't have a closing parenthesis, which is causing a javascript error making the function not run at all:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(e){
       if (jQuery.fn.tablesorter) {
           alert("pluginloaded");
       }
       jQuery.tablesorter();
   });
   ```
2. The second issue is that tablesorter is not being called properly. The line `jQuery.tablesorter();` is trying to call the tablesorter function, but that is just an object that contains all of the tablesorter plugin functions.

   To actually call the plugin, you need to use a jQuery selector followed by the tablesorter function (this is why `jQuery.fn.tablesorter` works - it's [jQuery's alias to the prototype property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean))

   ```
   $(function (e) {
       if (jQuery.fn.tablesorter) {
           alert("pluginloaded");
       }
       // jQuery.tablesorter(); // not the way to call the plugin
       $('table').tablesorter();
   });
   ```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3634/) to show it working.