# Center viewport on div, not div in viewport

Tags: jquery

I am building a list, with an auto overflow. Currently when a list is clicked it expands to show more content via jquery. When it does this with a list element originally below the viewport of the screen it goes to the top and you have to scroll to see what you clicked. Is there a way to either keep the screen from moving or to center on the element that was clicked so it remains in view?

The code is below:

```
       $('.expand').click(function() {
              $(".expanding-tab").hide();
              $(this).siblings('.expanding-tab').toggle();
              $('.main-tab').removeClass('tab-highlight');
              $(this).children('.main-tab').toggleClass('tab-highlight');
        });
```

Comment: Giving the element an id would allow you to set the hash in the URL, making the top of the browser align with the top of the element that has the corresponding id

Comment: Then, to use the id correctly, I'd have to give each individual element a unique id in a list of thousands?

Comment: You can just set the id to `"list-item-" + i`, where i is incremented with each item. Then when one is clicked, simple request `this.id` and set the hash to that.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without ids?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://web-design-weekly.com/snippets/scroll-to-position-with-jquery/

Comment: that worked like a charm, just have to clean it up a bit. Would you mind adding that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided below is based entirely on [this link](http://web-design-weekly.com/snippets/scroll-to-position-with-jquery/), which proposes a way to scroll the view of the browser to the position of an element. It contains some minor tweaks to suit the question that was askek. I also extensively commented the code, since the link lacks severely in explaination.

```
// jQuery.fn is shorthand for jQuery.prototype and allows
// for the extension of the jQuery function set with
// custom functions.
// See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean
jQuery.fn.scrollView = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        // This gives us the amount of pixels that is between
        // the element and the top of the window.
        var margin_top = jQuery(this).offset().top

        // Here you can define an offset that leaves some space at the top
        // of the element
        var offset = 10px;

        // Calling .animate() on the body and html objects
        // makes the transition of these elements smooth (the duration
        // of the transition is provided in the second argument in ms)
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            // Setting the scrollTop property makes the page scroll 
            // upwards by the specified amount pixels.
            // Setting scrollTop to margin_top makes the page scroll up
            // the exact amount of pixels to make the element appear
            // at the top of the window.
            scrollTop: margin_top + offset
        }, 200);
    });
}
```

After adding this function to the jQuery prototype, you can now call it on any element you want.

```
// Calling scrollView on the selected element(s) calls the function
// we defined above and makes the page scroll so that that element
// is now at the top (with an optional offset)
jQuery('#my-element').scrollView();
```

Finally, this is how you would add it as an onClick event to your element:

```
// Bind an onClick event listener to all elements with the 'expand' class
jQuery('.expand').click(function(event) {
    // Optionally you can use preventDefault() if it fits your needs
    event.preventDefault();

    // Call the scrollView function on the clicked element
    jQuery(this).scrollView();
});
```

Comment: So does not appreciate link only answers, please add some information regarding your approach.

Comment: I did not know that, however OP asked for me to provide it as answer, since it is what helped him. I will add some insight about the solution to the post in a minute.

Comment: I did ask him to repost this, but perhaps for the sake of keeping SO happy you can just copy the text from the link? it was pretty short. As a side note, is there a way to offset it a bit? Like 100 pixels from the top instead of right on it?

Comment: I editted my post, BenjaminPaul, could you retract your downvote? I changed the code slightly and also commented it extensively.

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek This is not working in Firefox, I changed the `jquery('html, body').animate` to `jquery('.container')` and it still did not work, although the functionality improved in chrome.

Comment: What version of firefox are you using, `jQuery('html, body').animate()` should work in firefox, see: http://jsfiddle.net/4etct/238/

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek I'm running FF35 on mac. The issue was I was running prevent default too late. It works crossbrowser now. Thanks!