# $.fn and named variable difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

I'm starting to learn how to create a jquery plugin where the documentation recommend me to use $.fn

For example:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
```

Then my question is, what is the advantage of using $.fn? Why can't I just assign a new variable to it and achieve the same result if they just want to be able to call that function like so:

```
var greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
```

Comment: Because a function is not a method. Notice that `.fn` is an alias for `.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the fn property is just an alias to the prototype property.

*Look this:* [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)