# jQuery Plugins: Unexpected behavior - context of "this" is probably lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I've written a really basic jQuery plugin that should log the value of a button clicked.

While it basically works, it unfortunately logs the same value for each button on the page. So if there are three buttons on the page, the value of the button clicked is logged three times.

The plugin code looks like this:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.content = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $('button').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
      });
    });
  };

}(jQuery));


$('button').content();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5jy7Lk8/)

Although I am quite puzzled right now, I am pretty sure that it has something to do with the context of `this` inside the `each` loop, but I can't really figure it out.

Comment: You aren't even using `this` in the `each` callback?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues going on here. The `this` inside of the `fn.content` function is actually the composed jQuery object. That object was `$('button')` so it will contain how ever many buttons there are in the DOM at that moment.

Then you iterate that set, and for each item in that set, you attach a click handler again to the `$('button')` group explicitly. Unfortunately this means that you have assigned a click event handler to that group n times where n is how many buttons there were. 3 buttons, 3 events; 6 buttons, 6 events.

In order to not do that, simply assign the click handler to the original jQuery object.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.content = function() {
        return this.click(function() {
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Keep in mind that `click` will internally call `.each`, and that `this` in our example is `$('button')` already.

For more information on creating jQuery plugins, please see my post on **[the utility of jQuery.fn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16026484/1026459)**

Comment: haha you wrote it before I had a chance! Here's a fiddle additionally:
https://jsfiddle.net/ft5jenwp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which scope you actually need access to, but scope of `this` is different for each function, including anonymous functions that you created. To access `this` of an outer scope, try something like the following:

```
function foo() {
    this.someVal = 1;
    var that = this;
    function bar() {
        console.log(that.someVal); // you have access to foo's this
    } 
}
```

Comment: The issue doesn't really have anything to do with `this` or scope.