# how to invoke hook before calling css , html functions using in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I meet the requirement where i get the js statements from the user and apply to the page

for some reason i have to keep track state of the element

i am facing problem when user gives the statments like

```
$("someselector").css("color":"red");
```

or

```
$("someselector").html("new text");
```

i will get the statements and apply in page, here i am not able to take the backup of original element

is there any way in jquery where i can call a hook function before calling css , html function and take the element backup

Comment: maybe [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)  ?

Comment: but when i can call clone if i get the statement from user and apply

Comment: When you use `var clonedObj = $('some_selector').clone()` you cloned the object to clonedObj. This can be your backup element. After you do the `$("someselector").html("new text");` you still have the clonedObj element with unchanged text.

Comment: Agree,But here selectors are given by the user dynamically, they simply give the input  statement like below as   $("someselector").html("new text"); , so i (app) cant guess the selector, so cant backup in normal way

Comment: Hmm. So I think you should find the selector with regex from the given string. I don't know any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the css function of jquery to achieve this.

You may need this: [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

```js
function backup($dom) {
  //console.log("backup dom:", $dom);
  $("h3").after($dom);
}
var fn = {
  css: $.fn.css
};
$.fn.css = function() {
  backup(this.clone());
  return fn.css.apply(this, arguments);
}
$("#a").css("color", "red");
$("#a").css("color", "red");
$("#a").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">element</div>
<h3>backup:</h3>
```