# $.fn equivalent in angularjs (using angular.element)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm doing a directive unit test using jasmine.

I have this test working now, but I must replace the `$.fn` using the equivalent for angularjs, (because in my company they don't let us use `$`)

**Code:**

```
(function scrollTopEventDirective(application) {
  'use strict';

  application.services.directive('scrollTopEvent', ['$rootScope', function scrollTopEvent($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.$on(attrs.scrollTopEvent, function onScope(event, top) {
          element.animate({ scrollTop: top || 0 }, 500);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
})(window.application);
```

**Test:**

```
(function scrollTopEventTest() {
  'use strict';

  describe('Directive: scrollTopEvent', function scrollTopEvent() {

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $compile, $scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function beforeFunction(_$compile_, $rootScope) {
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    describe('Scroll set top property', function scrollTopEventTest() {
      it('should call the scroll top event without value', function scrollTopEventTest() {
        var div = angular.element('<div style="overflow:scroll; width:100px; height:100px;" scroll-top-event="main-scroll-top"><br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x</div>');
        $compile(div)($scope);
        spyOn($.fn, 'animate');
        $scope.$emit('main-scroll-top');
        $scope.$digest();
        expect(div.animate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
      });    
  });
})();
```

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. ` $.fn` is very specific to jQuery. Angular is conceptually different from jQuery and doesn't have and "equivalent" to `$.fn`. If your company doesn't allow `$` anywhere in your code, you are going to struggle with Angular.

Comment: I understand, so how can I replace $.fn using angular.element or something like that?

Comment: To do what? You haven't explained what you need to accomplish. Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: By `$.fn`, you do mean jQuery's [alias for it's `prototype` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4083362/3478010), don't you? And if so, why on earth would Angular want to replace it?

Comment: Sorry, my goal is to replace thie line "spyOn($.fn, 'animate');" for something witout the $.fn. Idk why, but when I use the spyOn without the $.fn is not working, so I need that but I cant use it in that form. That make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `angular.element.prototype`

`jQuery.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`. In AngularJS, `angular.element` is an alias for `jQuery`.  So use `angular.element.prototype`.

From the Docs:

> If `jQuery` is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function. If jQuery is not available, `angular.element` delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or **jqLite**.
>
> To use `jQuery`, simply ensure it is loaded before the `angular.js` file. You can also use the `ngJq` directive to specify that jqlite should be used over jQuery, or to use a specific version of jQuery if multiple versions exist on the page.
>
> [— AngularJS `angular.element` API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)