# jQuery validate resetForm not working added to Onclick checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I wrote a small script which copies the billing address to the delivery address form fields onclick of a checkbox.

I have added `validate.resetForm();` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2086363/560287): to ensure that the current form errors are cleared.

This doesn't seem to be working and clearing no errors.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c5Qkt/

Steps:

1. Click the "Save" button, displays error messages.
2. Enter details in "Billing Address"
3. Check the "Same as Booking information"

How can I clear all errors and maybe even re-validate the form after click the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `resetForm` is a method on the validator object returned by `validate.validate(...)`, and not on the jQuery object itself. Fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pjucc/

```
var theForm = $(".validate");
var validate = null;
if (theForm.length) {
    validate = theForm.validate({ ... });
}
:
validate.form();
```

The function you want to trigger validation instead is [`.form()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form)

Comment: Heh, I'm sure we've all done worse. It's not amazingly clear from their docs either - I ended up reading the jquery.validator.js code.