# How an I get all form elements (input, textarea & select) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there an easy way (without listing them all separately) in jquery to select all form elements and only form elements.

I can't use children() etc because the form contains other HTML.

E.g:

```
$("form").each(function(){
    let $inputs = $("input, textarea, select", this);
});
```

Answer (score 213, accepted):

**Edit:** As pointed out in comments ([Mario Awad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select/12862623?noredirect=1#comment43823458_12862623) & [Brock Hensley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select/12862623?noredirect=1#comment24939806_12862623)), use `.find` to get the children

```
$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).find(':input') //<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});
```

forms also have an elements collection, sometimes this differs from children such as when the form tag is in a table and is not closed.

```js
var summary = [];
$('form').each(function () {
    summary.push('Form ' + this.id + ' has ' + $(this).find(':input').length + ' child(ren).');
    summary.push('Form ' + this.id + ' has ' + this.elements.length + ' form element(s).');
});

$('#results').html(summary.join('<br />'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="A" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="B" style="display: none;">
    <select><option>A</option></select>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<table bgcolor="white" cellpadding="12" border="1" style="display: none;">
<tr><td colspan="2"><center><h1><i><b>Login
Area</b></i></h1></center></td></tr>
<tr><td><h1><i><b>UserID:</b></i></h1></td><td><form id="login" name="login" method="post"><input
name="id" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td><h1><i><b>Password:</b></i></h1></td><td><input name="pass"
type="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><center><input type="button" value="Login"
onClick="pasuser(this.form)"></center></td><td><center><br /><input
type="Reset"></form></td></tr></table></center>
<div id="results"></div>
```

---

May be [**:input**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector is what you want

<s>$("form").each(function(){
    $(':input', this)//<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});</s>

As pointed out in docs

> To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input").

You can use like below,

```
$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).filter(':input') //<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});
```

Comment: Thanks although after reading: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector performance being an issue I may as well list them. Good to know its possible though

Comment: Is it just me or does this not work for `select`? EDIT: nevermind, works with select if I use `find(':input')`

Comment: You have to use "find" instead of "filter" in here as "filter" cannot work on a single element (in this case the "this" element). Using "filter" you will not be able to select any form elements and not only "select" elements. Thanks for @Brock Hensley for pointing this out.

Comment: How about large forms? I have a huge form with more than 4000+ elements in it, and this selector is very slow. In the specification is written that :input is not browser optimized by the CSS3, so does not work for me :/ .
Any other ideas?

Comment: @VasilPopov The above may be too slow for you. You could try couple of solutions, either way you need to group fewer elements and select them.

Comment: In later versions of jQuery you should be able to use serializeArray() to get the names and values of the form elements like so:
`var formElementNames = $("#form-identifier").serializeArray();`
With this, you could identify elements by their names. Not sure about the performance of this method however.

Comment: Did jquery break something? I get `VM364:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).each is not a function`

Answer (score 64):

The below code helps to get the details of elements from the specific form with the form id,

```
$('#formId input, #formId select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

The below code helps to get the details of elements from all the forms which are place in the loading page,

```
$('form input, form select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

The below code helps to get the details of elements which are place in the loading page even when the element is not place inside the  tag,

```
$('input, select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

**NOTE:** We add the more element tag name what we need in the object list like as below,

```
Example: to get name of attribute "textarea",

$('input, select, textarea').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        alert('Type: ' + input.attr('type') + 'Name: ' + input.attr('name') + 'Value: ' + input.val());
    }
);
```

Comment: Why this takes all the values and options of a select element, rather than giving the value of something that has been select or otherwise blank. ?

Comment: These selectors ignore radiobutton and checkboxes. which can be selected using `"formSelector:input"`. also it is not possible to read state of checkbox and radio buttons with `.val()` it has to be  verified with `":checked"`

Answer (score 17):

If you have additional types, edit the selector:

```
var formElements = new Array();
$("form :input").each(function(){
    formElements.push($(this));
});
```

All form elements are now in the array formElements.

Answer (score 11):

**JQuery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function** makes it pretty easy to get all form elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/55xnJ/2/

```
$("form").serialize(); //get all form elements at once 

//result would be like this:
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1
```

To compound on that idea: you can use something like this to make all form elements accessible.

```
Data = $('form').serialize().split('&');

for(i in Data){
    Data[i] = Data[i].split('=');
    Fields[ Data[i][0] ] = [ Data[i][1],
                             $('form *[name="' + Data[i][0] + '"]').eq(0) ];
}

console.log(Fields);

// The result would be a multi-dimensional array you could loop through
Fields[Field_Name] = [Field_Value, Field_Object]
```

Note: This will only work with named fields as serialize() will ignore all others. Any fields with duplicate names will be ignored. You could make a multi-dimensional array if multiple fields use the same name.

Comment: Use jQuery's serializeArray() instead. Saves the split().
  
`$("form").serializeArray(); //get all form elements at once `

Answer (score 8):

jQuery keeps a reference to the vanilla JS form element, and this contains a reference to all of the form's child elements. You could simply grab the reference and proceed forward:

```
var someForm = $('#SomeForm');

$.each(someForm[0].elements, function(index, elem){
    //Do something here.
});
```

Comment: As an alternative, `Object.entries($('form').get(0).elements).reduce((arr, [_, el]) => el.name ? Object.assign(arr, { [el.name]: el.value }) : arr, {})` will get you an object containing name:value of all form elements with non-empty name.

Answer (score 8):

**For the record**: The following snippet can help you **to get details about input, textarea, select, button, a** tags through a temp title when hover them.

[image]

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'mouseover', 'input, textarea, select, button, a', function() {
    var $tag = $( this );
    var $form = $tag.closest( 'form' );
    var title = this.title;
    var id = this.id;
    var name = this.name;
    var value = this.value;
    var type = this.type;
    var cls = this.className;
    var tagName = this.tagName;
    var options = [];
    var hidden = [];
    var formDetails = '';

    if ( $form.length ) {
        $form.find( ':input[type="hidden"]' ).each( function( index, el ) {
            hidden.push( "\t" + el.name + ' = ' + el.value );
        } );

        var formName = $form.prop( 'name' );
        var formTitle = $form.prop( 'title' );
        var formId = $form.prop( 'id' );
        var formClass = $form.prop( 'class' );

        formDetails +=
            "\n\nFORM NAME: " + formName +
            "\nFORM TITLE: " + formTitle +
            "\nFORM ID: " + formId +
            "\nFORM CLASS: " + formClass +
            "\nFORM HIDDEN INPUT:\n" + hidden.join( "\n" );
    }

    var tempTitle =
        "TAG: " + tagName +
        "\nTITLE: " + title +
        "\nID: " + id +
        "\nCLASS: " + cls;

    if ( 'SELECT' === tagName ) {
        $tag.find( 'option' ).each( function( index, el ) {
            options.push( el.value );
        } );

        tempTitle +=
            "\nNAME: " + name +
            "\nVALUE: " + value +
            "\nTYPE: " + type +
            "\nSELECT OPTIONS:\n\t" + options;

    } else if ( 'A' === tagName ) {
        tempTitle +=
            "\nHTML: " + $tag.html();

    } else {
        tempTitle +=
            "\nNAME: " + name +
            "\nVALUE: " + value +
            "\nTYPE: " + type;
    }

    tempTitle += formDetails;

    $tag.prop( 'title', tempTitle );
    $tag.on( 'mouseout', function() {
        $tag.prop( 'title', title );
    } )
} );
```

Comment: Great function! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is my favorite function and it works like a charm for me!

It returns an object with all for input, select and textarea data.

And it's trying to getting objects name by look for elements name else Id else class.

```
var form_data = get_form_data();
console.log(form_data);
```

Function:

```
function get_form_data(element){
    element = element || '';
    var all_page_data = {};
    var all_forms_data_temp = {};
    if(!element){
        element = 'body';
    }

    if($(element)[0] == undefined){
        return null;
    }

    $(element).find('input,select,textarea').each(function(i){
        all_forms_data_temp[i] = $(this);
    });

    $.each(all_forms_data_temp,function(){
        var input = $(this);
        var element_name;
        var element_value;

        if((input.attr('type') == 'submit') || (input.attr('type') == 'button')){
            return true;
        }

        if((input.attr('name') !== undefined) && (input.attr('name') != '')){
            element_name = input.attr('name').trim();
        } else if((input.attr('id') !== undefined) && (input.attr('id') != '')){
            element_name = input.attr('id').trim();
        } else if((input.attr('class') !== undefined) && (input.attr('class') != '')){
            element_name = input.attr('class').trim();
        }

        if(input.val() !== undefined){
            if(input.attr('type') == 'checkbox'){
                element_value = input.parent().find('input[name="'+element_name+'"]:checked').val();
            } else if((input.attr('type') == 'radio')){
                element_value = $('input[name="'+element_name+'"]:checked',element).val();
            } else {
                element_value = input.val();
            }
        } else if(input.text() != undefined){
            element_value = input.text();
        }

        if(element_value === undefined){
            element_value = '';
        }

        if(element_name !== undefined){
            var element_array = new Array();
            if(element_name.indexOf(' ') !== -1){
                element_array = element_name.split(/(\s+)/);
            } else {
                element_array.push(element_name);
            }

            $.each(element_array,function(index, name){
                name = name.trim();
                if(name != ''){
                    all_page_data[name] = element_value;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return all_page_data;
}
```

Comment: Nice but there is a subtle bug in "Element_Value = jQuery('input[name="'+Element_Name+'"]:checked').val();".
Element_Name might actually be the node id or class, in which case it won't find the element.

Comment: Correct, I have now fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

```
var $form_elements = $("#form_id").find(":input");
```

All the elements including the submit-button are now in the variable $form_elements.

Comment: How do you access them?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another way:

```
$('form[name=' + formName + ']').find(':input')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
function fieldsValidations(element) {
    var isFilled = true;
    var fields = $("#"+element)
        .find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();

    $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
        if (!field.value){
            isFilled = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return isFilled;
}
```

And use it as

```
$("#submit").click(function () {

    if(fieldsValidations('initiate')){
        $("#submit").html("<i class=\"fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin\"></i>");
    }
});
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

I used this way to get all input fields from a certain form:

```
$("#myForm").find("input").each(function() {
   // your stuff goes here
});
```

Or for the case here:

```
$("#myForm").find("select, textarea, input").each(function() {
   // your stuff goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Years later…

```js
const formElements = Object.entries($('form').get(0).elements)
    .reduce((arr, [_, el]) => 
        el.name 
            ? Object.assign(arr, { [el.name]: el.value }) 
            : arr, 
        {}
    );
```

The result is a simple key:value list of all form elements with a non-empty name.

For vanilla JS, replace `$('form').get(0)` with simple `document.querySelector('form')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<form action="/" id="searchForm">
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
event.preventDefault();

// Get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
url = $form.attr( "action" );

// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

// Put the results in a div
posting.done(function( data ) {
  var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
  $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
    });
  });
</script>
```

> Note the use of input[]

Comment: this doesn't seem to get textareas or selects

Answer (score 0):

all inputs:

```
var inputs = $("#formId :input");
```

all buttons

```
var button = $("#formId :button")
```

Answer (score 0):

## `const allFormElements = myForm.elements`

just use [the elements property for the form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) and no jquery needed.

if you are looking for all elements anywhere on the page:

[html control elements must be one of the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#value):
`button`,`fieldset`,`input`,`object`,`output`,`select`,`textarea`

so you can use JavaScript's native [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
// use query selector instead
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(
  ":where(button,fieldset,input,object,output,select,textarea)"
);
console.log({ nodes });
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="bob">
</div>
<div>
  <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50">Write something here</textarea>
</div>
```