# get Div Ids for leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to have multiple mapquest leaflet maps on one page, but in leaflet you have to create a map by using the id given in the div like so

```
     <div  style="color:black ;" id="map"></div>
```

and then

```
      plugin.Map =  new L.Map('map', {//<the id is used here
                layers : [mapLayer],
                center: new L.LatLng(39.828127,-98.579404),
                boxZoom: true,
                zoom: 5
            });
```

but What I was wondering if it is possible to get the ids if I have multiple div like:

```
    <div  style="color:black; " id="map"></div>
    <div  style="color:black ;" id="map2"></div>
```

and then I can call

```
   L.Map('map'...//where this is a possible array or something...
```

The reason I can't just put the ids in myself is I created a template and I want to do this without hardcoding anything...

Answer (score 3):

Give them class name `class="maps"` and then use jquery

```
<div  style="color:black" data-id="map1" class="maps"></div>
<div  style="color:black" data-id="map2" class="maps"></div>
<div  style="color:black" data-id="map3" class="maps"></div>
<div  style="color:black" data-id="map4" class="maps"></div>

<script>
    $().ready(function() {
        $(".maps").each(function(){
            var mapID = $(this).data('id');

            // do something

             plugin.Map = new L.Map(mapID, {//<the id is used here
                 layers : [mapLayer],
                 center: new L.LatLng(39.828127,-98.579404),
                 boxZoom: true,
                 zoom: 5
             });
        });
    );
</script>
```

Some resources:

[jquery get all form elements: input, textarea & select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: and instead of adding a class, if they're all in a div called `maps` you can use `$('#maps div')` with the above solution

Comment: This is also a possibility.

Comment: That seems to be working, but now, neither map is correct, and when I change the layer of one, the other goes grey, is it possible to have two maps being implemented like this?

Comment: My guess is that you might need separate API per map, this way you would not mangle API data across different maps. So when generating not only MapID, I would generate entirely separate API per map.