# Hide Add to Wishlist button for configurable products until an option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have an issue on a magento site where if a user adds a configurable product to the wishlist it throws a fatal error. What I'd like to do is add some javascript that hides the 'Add to Wishlist' button until the user has selected an configurable option -- but I have no idea how! Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You need to first hide the wishlist link by default and then you need to check the input element is selected or not You can read this jquery snipt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked...

In template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml I added the following:

```
<?php
if($_product->getTypeID() === 'configurable') {
    // Hide the button until a selection has been made
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".add-to-links").hide();

    jQuery(".super-attribute-select").on("change", function() {

        var val = jQuery(".super-attribute-select").val();
        if(val == '') {
            jQuery(".add-to-links").hide();
        }
        else {
            jQuery(".add-to-links").show();
        }

    });

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

To hide "Add to Wishlist",Go to the admin section and then select  system -> configuration, look at customers tabs in the left side, click Wishlist, on General Options -> Enable choose No and click Save Config.It will disable "Add to wishlist" link.