# How to grab all child inputs of a specifc div/form using just javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select), however I want to do something similar using javascript. Basically there a method to grab all user input in some container such as a div or form

```
<form>
<div>
   <text>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea>
</div>    
 <div>
   <select>
</div>
</form>
```

An example would be to grab text, textarea, select, and other forms of user input. I saw something like

```
var elements = document.myform.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

But it wouldn't work for selects. I know I could possibly just have a duplicate method which attempts to find **("select")** but what if the form must keep the order in which user put in information.

EDIT: Thank you for all the responses. Does all the methods mentioned so far only work if the inputs are direct descendants or is there some other method?

Comment: Ah  I did not know querySelectorAll  method could have multiple parameters Thank you.

Comment: If you have only `div` among those _form elements_ you can use `:not()`, e.g. `element.querySelectorAll('*:not(div)')`

Comment: @QwertyQwerts `querySelectorAll` find all children/descendants within e.g. in your case a `form`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a query selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#divID input, #divID select, #divID textarea');
//selects all elements contained by #divId that are input, textarea, or select elements
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<form>
<input type="text">
<select>
<option>1</option>
</select>
<textarea>Text...</textarea>
<div>
 <span>
     <select id="nestedSelect"></select>
 </span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv input, #myDiv select, #myDiv textarea');
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  console.log(inputs[i]);
}
</script>
```

You can also get the `div` or `form` first and then use `querySelectorAll` on it to get all the `input`s, `select`s and `textarea`s contained by it (not just direct children).

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <textarea>Text...</textarea>
  <div>
  <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div>
   <span>
     <select id="nestedSelect">
      <option value="2">2</option>
     </select>
   </span>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
var divElem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var inputElements = divElem.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea");
for(let i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){
    console.log(inputElements[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#divID > input, #divID > select');` should be better

Comment: Can you explain how your thing works (mainly the > part)? It is pretty different from how NIckHTTPS did his.

Comment: Oh, does you thing work for child of child's like if an input or select is inside another div under the original div? Like a grandchild or further?

Comment: @QwertyQwerts Well, _NIckHTTPS_ idea of `querySelectorAll("input select textarea")` is not gonna work, as that is not how to do it

Comment: @QwertyQwerts It selects all direct children of `#divID` that are `input`s or `select`s.

Comment: @LGSon Could I  use a while loop so it goes through all divs to make sure you grab every single input or is there a better way?

Comment: @LGSon based on the markup he provided that JS will work perfectly. Of course you want to be more specific with your selectors but the concept remain the same: use `querySelectorAll`...

Comment: @QwertyQwerts As I wrote in a comment at your question, `querySelectorAll` will find _all_ elements within a given parent, no matter how deep down they are, or siblings. Just create a complex markup and try it out.

Comment: @QwertyQwerts I have provided a second solution that selects all the `input`, `select`, and `textarea` elements as long as the `div` contains them (not necessarily being their direct parent).

Comment: @hev1 Thank you so much. I should have mentioned that in the first place too.

Comment: @QwertyQwerts No problem.

Comment: The first example given in this answer is still a bit off: `document.querySelectorAll('#divID > input, select, textarea');` will also include `select` and `textarea` elements that are not a child of `#divID`.  Should be `#divID > input, #divID > select, #divID > textarea` (as pointed out in the very first comment above!)

Comment: @DanielBeck Fixed it.

Comment: @hev1 In your first sample, remove all the child selectors `>`

Comment: Ah, goodness yes, my mistake, that probably shouldn't be a direct-child selection, it should be `#divID input, #divID select` etc).   We're all getting a bit tangled here aren't we

Comment: @DanielBeck Guess so :)

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for telling me. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**`.querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) specifying each of the elements separated by a `,` to select from the form:

```
var elements = form.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
```

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var elements = form.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');

elements.forEach(function(element) {
  // access each element here
  console.log(element);
});
```

```css
input, textarea, select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="name">
  <textarea>text</textarea>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call( document.getElementById('parentobject').querySelectorAll( 'input[type="text"], input[type="hidden"], input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], select, textarea' ), function( elem ) { 
    console.log( elem.id);
} );

<div id="parentobject">
<input id="textinput" type="text" value="xyz" />
<input id="gobutton" type="button" value="go" />
<input id="acheckedbox" type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

For each element found within the specified element object (parentobject) of the types specified within the queryselectorAll filters, the specified inline function will be run with it as target, outputting the element's id to the console.

The above code applied to the following html would output the id of each matching element:

```
textinput
acheckedbox
```

Comment: Would be nice if you'd add some explanation about the code