# Get All Form Elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to get all elements from Form using JavaScript. I have tried the below method but I am still unable to extract all elements.

Are there any suggestions anyone can provide to extract all Form elements information?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // References:
        var $form = $('#rForm');
        var $subm = $('#submitForm');
        var $impt = $form.find(':option, :input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');
     // Submit function:
        $form.submit(function(){
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
          // On success, clear all inputs;
                $impt.val('').attr('value','').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
            },'json');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: you get only the form with id `#rForm'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery get all form elements: input, textarea & select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select)

Comment: @NikosM. That's my form id. Should I not use that?

Comment: by all means, but that will get you only that form, not others if there are on the page

Comment: @NikosM. yea, I just need to extract the information from the Form. I've included the <select> element in the form.

Comment: You are doing it right, but I guess you have problem with resetting your form after ajax call, right?

Comment: What is `:option` you are trying to select? It's not a valid selector

Comment: @MeghdadHadidi

I tried with :select (<select> element) but didn't work. Then, I tried with :option (<option> tag under the <select> element) but it still doesn't work. And yes, I do have problem with resetting the Form.

Comment: try just using `option` 
see this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hopper-m3zen

Comment: @MeghdadHadidi
Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried that and it's still not working.

Comment: In the example I've sent in the previous comment the submit button is resetting the form, even the selected `option` is being deselected. If that's not the case, can you please create a sandbox like what I've created and try re-producing the issue?