# how to select all inputs in a form

Tags: input, jquery-selectors

i am a student trying to make a trivia form, I want to alert the user if none of the inputs was filled i am new to js I need simple results please :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery get all form elements: input, textarea & select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862601/jquery-get-all-form-elements-input-textarea-select).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.