# jQuery unobtrusive form validator is not hiding error messages when resetting the form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am attempting to properly validate and reset a form. The validation works fine -- fields which are required are successfully monitored. However, when I go to reset my form -- I only see the red background for my inputs clear, not the validation messages.

According to the [jQuery validate documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm):

> Resets input fields to their original value (requires form plugin),
>   removes classes indicating invalid elements and **hides error messages**.

Here's all the info I think is relevant to the issue. Please let me know if you would like to see anything else.

Here is how I generate a DOM element in my Model. This element needs validation:

```
//Model.ascx
<div class="detailsRow required">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Site) %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSiteID, new SelectList(Model.Site, "Key", "Value"))%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedSiteID)%>
</div>

//Model.cs
[DisplayName("Site")]
public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Site { get; set; }

[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Site required")]
public int SelectedSiteID { get; set; }
```

Site is a select list which starts with a value of -1. Any other selection is valid. As such, I validate on a range from 0 to max.

Over in JavaScript, I run the following code against my form when the user presses the 'Submit' button on the form:

```
var form = workflowDialogContent.find('form');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
//Maintain a reference to the current formValidator to be able to reset.
var formValidator = $.data(form[0], 'validator');

if (form.valid()) {
}
```

When the user pressed submit, the form is validated and my validation message is shown if the selected site has a value of -1.

Now, whenever the a selection is changed, I want to reset my form. I've taken this logic from: [How to clear Jquery validation error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086287/how-to-clear-jquery-validation-error-messages)

```
$(window).on('change', '#SelectedSiteID', function () {
    //Returns the formValidator we maintained a reference to.
    var validator = WorkflowDialogBuilder.getCurrentFormValidator();
    validator.resetForm();
    //TODO: resetForm's documentation says that it hides the errors, but I did not experience this, so I am doing it manually.
    //$('.field-validation-error').empty();
}
```

However, when I run this code... the highlighting is removed, but the error messages remain. If I call the bit of commented code -- the validation errors are hidden, but they do not re-appear the next time my form is validated.

After validating:
[image]
After calling resetForm:
[image]

Any ideas why I would be seeing such behavior?

**Update:** As a work around, the following bit of code seems to do proper clean-up:

```
$('.field-validation-error').empty();
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the validation does not show and hide the error messages, but simply add text to a span which is always visible. For your manual solution to work just do the same and empty the ".field-validation-error" manually... As per why it does not work out of the box, I don't know... :/

Comment: Good idea. That is a viable workaround which does the trick, but I will leave this open for a while. Thank you!

Comment: If you're dymaically loading that dialog form you might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406291/jquery-validate-unobtrusive-not-working-with-dynamic-injected-elements

Comment: By the way, why are you calling the .parse() method yourself? Isn't that something that the unobtrusive library from Microsoft does already at the very beginning?

Comment: What do you mean by 'does already at the very beginning?' I didn't experience validation effects if I do not call parse.

Comment: Tallmaris should have phrased it better to be clearer, but what he means is that the unobtrusive library hooks into the DOM ready event (the same as $(function)) to rig the forms itself. This can be found toward the very end of the file: $jQval.unobtrusive.parse(document);

Comment: If elements are loaded dynamically, the library hooking into the DOM ready event may be doing so before the elements are loaded; in that case parse would need to be called separately after the dynamic elements are loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear Jquery validation error messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086287/how-to-clear-jquery-validation-error-messages)

Answer (score 2):

why not [trigger element validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/) as soon as the field is altered

```
$('#myFormId input').on('change', function(){
    validator.element($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add this to your workaround :

```
var form = $("#MyFormId");
form.find(':input').removeClass("input-validation-error");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the answers given thus far is that all of the errors go away instead of just the one you want.  I had a similar problem with getting an address and if the state is DC I am requiring the entry of the quadrant(NW,NE,SW,SE).  I add and remove the requirement with jquery and then wrap the @Html.ValidationMessageFor() in a div, then I simply hide the div when a different state is selected.

Answer (score 0):

you are using below, correct?

```
var form = workflowDialogContent.find('form');
```

then you must use

```
form.resetForm();
```

to reset the form, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
validator.resetForm();
```