# jquery validation messages are visible even after closing the ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate plugin. I have a html form inside jquery ui dialog. When user open the dialog and try to submit the form and if form contains validation error and at the same time if user close the dialog and when he open it again than validation messages are still there. I have created a fiddle also :

http://jsbin.com/aralur/4/edit

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086287/how-to-clear-jquery-validation-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

just use this way:

```
$('.ui-icon-closethick').click(function(){
    $('.error').text('');
});
```

and see that in the working bin here -

> **http://jsbin.com/aralur/5/edit**

.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer is required if this helped you to achieve your result. Any more suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the error message before opening the dialog box as given below :) It's a simplistic way of doing this.

```
$("#order").bind("click", function(){ 
  $("label.error").hide();
  $("#orderform").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, i also found a solution for the problem which i want to share with you
. We can use a `resetForm()` function of jquery.validate plugin at `beforeClose event` of jquery ui dialog. Here`s a working fiddle :

http://jsbin.com/aralur/11/edit