# How to clear validation on reset button, and make it continue to show if submit is pressed again

Tags: jquery, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validation-engine

Each input has:

```
@Html.LabelFor
@Html.EditorFor
@Html.ValidationMessageFor
```

The validation message has a class of 'text-danger'.  On submitting incorrect values, the errors appear properly.  I added a Clear button with type="reset" but this only resets the input fields, not the validation messages.

I am aware of a similar question: [How to clear Jquery validation error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086287/how-to-clear-jquery-validation-error-messages)

But, I need a clear explanation of whether to change the existing jquery.validation scripts, or how to write a separate script.  Also, given the above criteria, how to format the onclick event of the reset button.

Comment: Travis J's answer is not a modification to the validation scripts.  You'd add that code to your page.  He gives two versions (the second version is minified).  You would call `$("#formId").clearValidation();` when the clear button is clicked.

Comment: Does it matter if the id of the form is declared on @Html.BeginForm or <div class = "form-horizontal"?

Comment: you'd want the actual form id (@Html.BeginForm), and not the div, although if there isn't any extra content on your page other than what's in the form, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Ok thanks, that is where  I have it.  Now I am getting an error:  **Cannot read property 'resetForm' of undefined** in the console.  Do I have to change '[name]' in the clearValidation function?  Just to clarify, on 'click' of the clear button I am calling the clearValidation function using the id of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a console error with Travis J's solution: 'cannot read property of 'resetForm' undefined...'

I used Nick Craver's answer to hide the error classes on Clear, and show them again on Submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#clear').click(function () {
            $(".has-error").hide();
            $(".text-danger").hide();
        });
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $(".has-error").show();
            $(".text-danger").show();
        });
    });
```

All validation still works.