# JQuery validate after return View("Create", host) from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that I would like to use for creating a new record and modify it.
When I run it to create a new record validation works fine:

```
                    @if(Model == null){
                        <input type="text" id="txt_hostname" name="txt_hostname" class="form-control" value="PC-Name1-test">
                    } else {
@*                         @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.Hostname,
                            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @id = "txt_hostname", name="txt_hostname" } }) *@
                        <input type="text" id="txt_hostname" name="txt_hostname" class="form-control" value="@Model.Hostname">         
                    }
```

but when I fill the "same" input with information from the model, the jquery validator does not fire anymore when I change the input text. I noticed that the class also contains "valid" that does not change:
class="form-control valid"

Modify:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_hostname" name="txt_hostname" class="form-control valid" aria-invalid="false">
```

Create new one:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_hostname" name="txt_hostname" class="form-control" value="PC-Name1-test">
```

My Jquery looks like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var form = $("#form_endpointadmin");

    $("#form_endpointadmin").validate({
        ignore: [],
        errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
        rules: {
            txt_hostname:{
                required: true,
                regex: "^.{2,}$"
            }
        },
        
        messages: {
            txt_hostname: "Please enter a valid hostname."
          
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
            },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
                //$(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
                $(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('form-control');
            }
    });

    // Reapply validation rules after loading the content
    //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

    //form.removeData("validator")
    //.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

    //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

});
```

I read something about a DOM thing, but could not find a way around it, only when using ajax.
So how can I re-validate a value that was already valid once, but can be changed now and has to be verified again?

Thanks
Stephan

---

Edit:
I changed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function () {
```

which is waiting for the DOM. Not sure if this is a good way

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2086287/1026459